# Laravel DatePicker keeps pushing the previous month rather than the month that is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, datepicker

I'm really stumped as to where this error is occurring in this Tailwind UI Datepicker. If I select 09-08-2021 on the visual Datepicker, the value gets saved as 09-07-2021.

I have read up on other similiar experiences where somewhere the month value needs a +1 as the month starts on 0 when it should be 1, but everywhere I have tried adding a 1 so far I have not succeeded in getting the right date.

Prior to the script:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.js" defer></script>
  <style>
    [x-cloak] {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div></div>
<div x-data="app()" x-init="[initDate(), getNoOfDays()]" x-cloak>
  <div class="container mx-auto px-4 py-2 md:py-10">
    <div class="mb-5 w-64">
      <label for="datepicker" class="font-bold mb-1 text-gray-700 block">Select Date</label>
      <div class="relative">
        <input type="hidden" name="date" x-ref="date">
        <input type="text" readonly x-model="datepickerValue" @click="showDatepicker = !showDatepicker" @keydown.escape="showDatepicker = false" class="w-full pl-4 pr-10 py-3 leading-none rounded-lg shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline text-gray-600 font-medium" placeholder="Select date">
        <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 px-3 py-2">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-400"  fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div  class="bg-white mt-12 rounded-lg shadow p-4 absolute top-0 left-0" style="width: 17rem" x-show.transition="showDatepicker" @click.away="showDatepicker = false">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-2">
          <div>
            <span x-text="MONTH_NAMES[month]" class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-800"></span>
            <span x-text="year" class="ml-1 text-lg text-gray-600 font-normal"></span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="transition ease-in-out duration-100 inline-flex cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 p-1 rounded-full" :class="{'cursor-not-allowed opacity-25': month == 0 }" :disabled="month == 0 ? true : false"  @click="month--; getNoOfDays()">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-500 inline-flex"  fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 19l-7-7 7-7"/>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="transition ease-in-out duration-100 inline-flex cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 p-1 rounded-full" :class="{'cursor-not-allowed opacity-25': month == 11 }" :disabled="month == 11 ? true : false" @click="month++; getNoOfDays()">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-500 inline-flex"  fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7"/>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap mb-3 -mx-1">
          <template x-for="(day, index) in DAYS" :key="index">
            <div style="width: 14.26%" class="px-1">
              <div x-text="day" class="text-gray-800 font-medium text-center text-xs">
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-1">
          <template x-for="blankday in blankdays">
            <div style="width: 14.28%" class="text-center border p-1 border-transparent text-sm">
        </div>
      </template>
      <template x-for="(date, dateIndex) in no_of_days" :key="dateIndex">
        <div style="width: 14.28%" class="px-1 mb-1">
          <div @click="getDateValue(date)" x-text="date" class="cursor-pointer text-center text-sm leading-none rounded-full leading-loose transition ease-in-out duration-100" :class="{'bg-blue-500 text-white': isToday(date) == true, 'text-gray-700 hover:bg-blue-200': isToday(date) == false }"
```

The script:

```
 <script>
   const MONTH_NAMES = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
   const DAYS = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

   function app() {
     return {
       showDatepicker: false,
       datepickerValue: '',
       month: '',
       year: '',
       no_of_days: [],
       blankdays: [],
       days: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
       initDate() {
         let today = new Date();
         this.month = today.getMonth();
         this.year = today.getFullYear();
         this.datepickerValue = new Date(this.year, this.month, today.getDate()).toDateString();
       },
       isToday(date) {
         const today = new Date();
         const d = new Date(this.year, this.month, date);
         return today.toDateString() === d.toDateString() ? true : false;
       },
       getDateValue(date) {
         let selectedDate = new Date(this.year, this.month, date);
         this.datepickerValue = selectedDate.toDateString();
         this.$refs.date.value = selectedDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ (('0'+ selectedDate.getMonth()).slice(2)) +"-"+ ('0' + selectedDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
         console.log(this.$refs.date.value);
         this.showDatepicker = false;
       },
       getNoOfDays() {
         let daysInMonth = new Date(this.year, this.month + 1, 0).getDate();

         // find where to start calendar day of week
         let dayOfWeek = new Date(this.year, this.month).getDay();
         let blankdaysArray = [];
         for ( var i=1; i <= dayOfWeek; i++) {
           blankdaysArray.push(i);
         }
         let daysArray = [];
           for ( var i=1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
             daysArray.push(i);
           }

           this.blankdays = blankdaysArray;
             this.no_of_days = daysArray;
           }
         }
       }
    </script>
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. Hopefully some extra eyes can see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just only +1 at `selectedDate.getMonth()+1`, because it's get index from `0 = january`

like this

```
// 2021-08-09    
this.$refs.date.value = selectedDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ('0'+ (selectedDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"-"+ ('0' + selectedDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

// 09-08-2021    
this.$refs.date.value = ('0' + selectedDate.getDate()).slice(-2) +"-"+ ('0'+ (selectedDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"-"+ selectedDate.getFullYear();
```

demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v5xk78eg/1/

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it changes the saved month to "01" instead no matter what date you select.

Comment: how do you get the date when you save it?

Comment: $request->date, that's what gets saved to the database.

Comment: show me your view code, because the problem is in the view when sending parameters

Comment: I added the section prior to the script if that's what you meant, as the wrong value keeps getting pushed to the database table.

Comment: i know it `(('0'+ selectedDate.getMonth()).slice(2))`, that's why **month to "01" instead no matter what date you select**. it should be like this `('0'+ (selectedDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)`